# awk split and reverse the order

Tags: awk

I have the following lines which are tab-separated.

```
NIATv7_g10470.t1    XP_019227081.1  100.0   878 0   0   1   878 1   878 0.0e+00 1599.7  99.9    MELKVSSPKPVFSTSDCNSDPEEKEISEDXXXXXXXXXXXXXTRSQSTETEALEPALRRPFRKRNKPFENGHPYQEGDSHSSDTRFGKRRGMGSFSRTPSDSYQMMRLNQSLSGHAAPGRGRGRESGAWGPCESRFSTIDIASQFVPQGPINPLLYTGRGPQNVSSGQGASWNAFGIVPGIPNGGLDTLHTLGLQGRLRTSLNPAMSMGIPRQRCRDFEERGFCLRGDMCPLEHGVNRIVVEDVQSLSKFNLPVSLPGAHTLGPATAQGPLPAISPSSSLANKALHNKSINPPVIDNGLGLTDTFGGGSVSGGADFYDPDQPLWSNDHPENSAALLDVNRSKIDDTGPMLDADSSDQDQVALCDGFKLERLVRDAGAASGSQSVWERTSRSKHKLQSFNSTQGINRHGKQTNVDTIDPQMVESSSEPQSSSGRNMRKPSQKALRTLFVSGVPQKDNKPEALLSHFQKFGEVIDIYIPMNGERAFVQFSKREEAEAALKAPDAVMGNRFIKLFWANRDSIMDNGTSGSSIFPLAPRGGTPSTVPPHLLFPHKRKDNLQTVAGKTAEQACGSVTVAPLATSDLPKPVAQNGLKTTPPLKKKLETLELLKEEMRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXKQAVGVKDEAAPDQAMNKPKGGGTVSNSGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXSRSTENAEPTCSKLSLTVAMHEASNLKQSIRPLAPVGAPFILNRYKLDNRPTTFKILPPLPSALANVDVLKEHFSTFGDPPSVELEDLEPKDCNDGSEVQNTSARISFRSRRSAERAFLNGKSWQGQILQLMWVQSSNPAKDVGVGENVTPASKQPSDANGQSNARNGVAGLPEGSVAGNHEPDNQGRREDE  MELKVSSPKPVFSTSDCNSDPEEKEISEDXXXXXXXXXXXXXTRSQSTETEALEPALRRPFRKRNKPFENGHPYQEGDSHSSDTRFGKRRGMGSFSRTPSDSYQMMRLNQSLSGHAAPGRGRGRESGAWGPCESRFSTIDIASQFVPQGPINPLLYTGRGPQNVSSGQGASWNAFGIVPGIPNGGLDTLHTLGLQGRLRTSLNPAMSMGIPRQRCRDFEERGFCLRGDMCPLEHGVNRIVVEDVQSLSKFNLPVSLPGAHTLGPATAQGPLPAISPSSSLANKALHNKSINPPVIDNGLGLTDTFGGGSVSGGADFYDPDQPLWSNDHPENSAALLDVNRSKIDDTGPMLDADSSDQDQVALCDGFKLERLVRDAGAASGSQSVWERTSRSKHKLQSFNSTQGINRHGKQTNVDTIDPQMVESSSEPQSSSGRNMRKPSQKALRTLFVSGVPQKDNKPEALLSHFQKFGEVIDIYIPMNGERAFVQFSKREEAEAALKAPDAVMGNRFIKLFWANRDSIMDNGTSGSSIFPLAPRGGTPSTVPPHLLFPHKRKDNLQTVAGKTAEQACGSVTVAPLATSDLPKPVAQNGLKTTPPLKKKLETLELLKEEMRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXKQAVGVKDEAAPDQAMNKPKGGGTVSNSGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXSRSTENAEPTCSKLSLTVAMHEASNLKQSIRPLAPVGAPFILNRYKLDNRPTTFKILPPLPSALANVDVLKEHFSTFGDPPSVELEDLEPKDCNDGSEVQNTSARISFRSRRSAERAFLNGKSWQGQILQLMWVQSSNPAKDVGVGENVTPASKQPSDANGQSNARNGVAGLPEGSVAGNHEPDNQGRREDE  MELKVSSPKPVFSTSDCNSDPEEKEISEDXXXXXXXXXXXXXTRSQSTETEALEPALRRPFRKRNKPFENGHPYQEGDSHSSDTRFGKRRGMGSFSRTPSDSYQMMRLNQSLSGHAAPGRGRGRESGAWGPCESRFSTIDIASQFVPQGPINPLLYTGRGPQNVSSGQGASWNAFGIVPGIPNGGLDTLHTLGLQGRLRTSLNPAMSMGIPRQRCRDFEERGFCLRGDMCPLEHGVNRIVVEDVQSLSKFNLPVSLPGAHTLGPATAQGPLPAISPSSSLANKALHNKSINPPVIDNGLGLTDTFGGGSVSGGADFYDPDQPLWSNDHPENSAALLDVNRSKIDDTGPMLDADSSDQDQVALCDGFKLERLVRDAGAASGSQSVWERTSRSKHKLQSFNSTQGINRHGKQTNVDTIDPQMVESSSEPQSSSGRNMRKPSQKALRTLFVSGVPQKDNKPEALLSHFQKFGEVIDIYIPMNGERAFVQFSKREEAEAALKAPDAVMGNRFIKLFWANRDSIMDNGTSGSSIFPLAPRGGTPSTVPPHLLFPHKRKDNLQTVAGKTAEQACGSVTVAPLATSDLPKPVAQNGLKTTPPLKKKLETLELLKEEMRXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXKQAVGVKDEAAPDQAMNKPKGGGTVSNSGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXSRSTENAEPTCSKLSLTVAMHEASNLKQSIRPLAPVGAPFILNRYKLDNRPTTFKILPPLPSALANVDVLKEHFSTFGDPPSVELEDLEPKDCNDGSEVQNTSARISFRSRRSAERAFLNGKSWQGQILQLMWVQSSNPAKDVGVGENVTPASKQPSDANGQSNARNGVAGLPEGSVAGNHEPDNQGRREDE* MELKVSSPKPVFSTSDCNSDPEEKEISEDDDDDRNHKHRRKDTRSQSTETEALEPALRRPFRKRNKPFENGHPYQEGDSHSSDTRFGKRRGMGSFSRTPSDSYQMMRLNQSLSGHAAPGRGRGRESGAWGPCESRFSTIDIASQFVPQGPINPLLYTGRGPQNVSSGQGASWNAFGIVPGIPNGGLDTLHTLGLQGRLRTSLNPAMSMGIPRQRCRDFEERGFCLRGDMCPLEHGVNRIVVEDVQSLSKFNLPVSLPGAHTLGPATAQGPLPAISPSSSLANKALHNKSINPPVIDNGLGLTDTFGGGSVSGGADFYDPDQPLWSNDHPENSAALLDVNRSKIDDTGPMLDADSSDQDQVALCDGFKLERLVRDAGAASGSQSVWERTSRSKHKLQSFNSTQGINRHGKQTNVDTIDPQMVESSSEPQSSSGRNMRKPSQKALRTLFVSGVPQKDNKPEALLSHFQKFGEVIDIYIPMNGERAFVQFSKREEAEAALKAPDAVMGNRFIKLFWANRDSIMDNGTSGSSIFPLAPRGGTPSTVPPHLLFPHKRKDNLQTVAGKTAEQACGSVTVAPLATSDLPKPVAQNGLKTTPPLKKKLETLELLKEEMRKKQEMLEQKRNEFRRKLDKLEKQAVGVKDEAAPDQAMNKPKGGGTVSNSGKVENSSPVEPSNTVSSPPSEATPDSSRSTENAEPTCSKLSLTVAMHEASNLKQSIRPLAPVGAPFILNRYKLDNRPTTFKILPPLPSALANVDVLKEHFSTFGDPPSVELEDLEPKDCNDGSEVQNTSARISFRSRRSAERAFLNGKSWQGQILQLMWVQSSNPAKDVGVGENVTPASKQPSDANGQSNARNGVAGLPEGSVAGNHEPDNQGRREDE  XP_019227081.1 PREDICTED: zinc finger CCCH domain-containing protein 41-like [Nicotiana attenuata]
```

I used this awk command to simplify the above line:

```
> awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\t" } ;{print $1","$18}' NIATT_r2.0.aa.combined_nr_XPonly.best_hit_addNoXP | head
NIATv7_g10470.t1,XP_019227081.1 PREDICTED: zinc finger CCCH domain-containing protein 41-like [Nicotiana attenuata]
```

I would like to split `$18` for the first space occourrence.

```
XP_019227081.1 PREDICTED: zinc finger CCCH domain-containing protein 41-like [Nicotiana attenuata]
```

The output of this split I would like to swap and separate by a tab.

```
PREDICTED: zinc finger CCCH domain-containing protein 41-like [Nicotiana attenuata]   XP_019227081.1
```

As a final result, I would like to combine `$1` with the reverse split result to achieve the below output:

```
NIATv7_g10470.t1,PREDICTED: zinc finger CCCH domain-containing protein 41-like [Nicotiana attenuata]       XP_019227081.1
```

How is it possible?

Comment: It looks like your original file is separated by a combination of spaces and tabs. Just leave `FS` set to its default (don't set it) and it will break on *whitespace* including either spaces or tabs. For instance, using the default `$1` is `NIATv7_g10470.t1` and `$18` is `XP_019227081.1` (`$19` is `PREDICTED:`)

Comment: Sorry, I  updated the input file in my question.

Comment: Could you maybe say just in plain English what you would like please, so I don't have to scroll right all the way to Japan and remember 20 strange (to me) fields. Thank you.

Comment: Is something like this what you are asking for? `awk '{print $1","$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$NF"\t\t"$18}'`

Comment: Sorry, for the confusen. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use GNU `awk`, with the `gensub` extension, you can try:

```
awk -F'\t' '{print $1 "," gensub(/(\S+)\s+(.*)/, "\\2\t\\1", "1", $18)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `split` function lets you split a value on an arbitrary regex.

```sh
awk -F '\t' '{ split($18, fields, / /);
    print $1 "," substr($18, length(fields[1]) + 2) "\t" fields[1]  }' NIATT_r2.0.aa.combined_nr_XPonly.best_hit_addNoXP
```

Alternatively, you can use `sub()` (or in Awk dialects which support it, `gsub()`) to perform a regex replacement directly on a value.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but it does not swap the split.

Comment: Oops, fixed now.